ERROR Error: getBlob() is only available in Browser-like environments
I am trying to fetch data from Firebase storage using Angularfire 18.0.1 :
import {Storage, getBlob, ref } from '@angular/fire/storage';

async ngOnInit() {
    const eventsRef = ref(this.storage, 'events');
    const blob =  await getBlob(eventsRef);
}

However, I get the following error:
ERROR Error: getBlob() is only available in Browser-like environments

What am I doing wrong?

Apparently, getBlob() is only supported on browser side. Since I have server-side-rendering enabled in my angular project, ngOnInit gets called on the server first. I managed to resolve the error by making sure the function is called on the browser side only:
private platformId: Object = inject(PLATFORM_ID);

async ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const eventsRef = ref(this.storage, 'events');
      const blob =  await getBlob(eventsRef);
    }
}

